# Deleting multiple sheets with common name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all sheets which contain "sheet" and then a number like "1" or "25" in a workbook. I have some code written which works but it is very inefficient and there has to be a better way.
Forgive me for my ugly code.

```
Sub DeleteextraSheets()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name = "Sheet1" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet2" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet3" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet4" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet5" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet6" And xWs.Name = "Sheet7" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet8" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet9" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet10" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet11" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet12" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet13" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet14" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet15" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet16" Or xWs.Name = "Sheet17" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator):

This will match all sheets starting with `Sheet` and then a number.

```vb
If Left(xWs.Name,6) Like "Sheet#" Then
   xWs.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Sheets

- The first two procedures will include charts and use `vbTextCompare`
  to allow case insensitivity i.e. `A = a`. Both issues are of utmost
  importance when checking the sheet names before adding new sheets and
  renaming them. In case of deleting, not so much.
- The 3rd and 4th procedure are also case insensitive i.e. `A = a`
- In the 3rd procedure you have to know all of the sheet names for it to work.
- The 4th procedure covers the scenario when you know the sheet names, but only some of them might occur in the workbook.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' If they start with a common string:
Sub deleteExtraSheets()
    
    Const CommonString As String = "Sheet"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Define Sheets Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
    
    ' The 'Sheets' collection includes charts, but there is no 'Sheet' object.
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = -1
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        ' vbTextCompare means 'A = a'.
        If StrComp(Left(sh.Name, Len(CommonString)), CommonString, _
                                                     vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            Data(j) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If j > -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve Data(j)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets(Data).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub

' If they contain a common string:
Sub deleteExtraSheets2()
    
    Const CommonString As String = "Sheet"
    ' I prefer 'ThisWorkbook', the workbook containing this code.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Define Sheets Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
    
    ' The 'Sheets' collection includes charts, but there is no 'Sheet' object.
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = -1
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        ' vbTextCompare means 'A = a'.
        If InStr(1, sh.Name, CommonString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            Data(j) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If j > -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve Data(j)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets(Data).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
End Sub

' If you know their names:
Sub deleteExtraSheets3()
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
                 "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", _
                 "Sheet11", "Sheet12", "Sheet13", "Sheet14", "Sheet15", _
                 "Sheet16", "Sheet17")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Data).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

' If you know their names and only some of them might occur:
Sub deleteExtraSheets4()
    
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
                      "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10", _
                      "Sheet11", "Sheet12", "Sheet13", "Sheet14", "Sheet15", _
                      "Sheet16", "SHEET17")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Define Sheets Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
    
    ' The 'Sheets' collection includes charts, but there is no 'Sheet' object.
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = -1
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, SheetNames, 0)) Then
            j = j + 1
            Data(j) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    If j > -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve Data(j)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets(Data).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```